# How to get authorization to work in the USA as a 100% telecommuter

Tags: telecommute

I live in Europe but Im looking for a remote job in the USA, meaning I want to work remotely from home (telecommute).I read "is authorized to work in the USA" as a requirement in most adds.

How do I get such authorization?

PS: Im sorry if the question is in the wrong stackexchange site. If it is, please tell me where should I post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My (U.S.) company has contractors that work in other countries (Canada, Chile).  It's outside my domain, but I know that working with contractors is much easier than working with employees in other countries from an accounting point-of-view.  Essentially we have only reporting requirements with contractors, but with employees we would have tax withholding and insurance requirements as well, and they would be unique to each country.

See if you can find contract work in the U.S.  It would really help your case if you did the legwork on what would be required of them to use you as a contractor:  What are the reporting requirements (Forms / Frequency / File Dates).

To hire contractors in the U.S., for instance, it requires only one annual 1099 form for each contractor, which must be submitted to the IRS and the contractor in January of each year if the total annual amount paid is $600 or more.  That's what info you need to determine for your country.

Also, this doesn't apply to you in Europe, but make sure your country and the U.S. don't have software export restrictions or banking restrictions between one another.

Comment: thank you. what is the chance that if those people are looking for an employee, but they think Im a great match, they'd hire me as a contractor instead?

Comment: @J.K. - If you don't ask, 0%.  Companies have a need that they are trying to meet, and they're willing to pay you to do it.  Larger companies may be trapped in their bureaucracy.  Medium and small companies may be very open to the idea, especially if you can help them understand the requirements.

Answer (score 4):

Wesley Long's answer is probably going to be the most practical use. However, to answer the question you asked, "authorized to work in the US" means that they are looking for someone who doesn't need to get a visa to work in the US - essentially a citizen or a permanent resident or (more rarely) someone who already has a transferrable work visa.

That doesn't mean they can't be persuaded to take a contractor who works overseas, but such an arrangement is much more complicated than having a US-based employee, and you would have to work hard to persuade them.

There are plenty of places on the web where you can read up about how to apply for US Permanent Residency, or a work visa.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that language was intended to mean work *IN* the USA, as in physically located here. I doubt they're looking for an international telecommuter. But the only way to find out is to ask them.

Comment: if they DO look for an international telecommuter, how do I go about getting authorization to work in the us (or by stressing on the IN word, you meant that this authorization is for people who actually work within the territory of the states)

Comment: As far as I know telecommuting across boundaries,  while an accounting disaster (which is why it's rare) doesn't require any special permission... so, yes, I think that they're looking for someone who can be legally employed on US soil. Sorry.

Comment: thank you, I hope they allow for non-residents to work for them as well...

Comment: ((When I was doing international work it required that I have managers in both countries, specifically so I could be paid from the in-country budgets to avoid that issue. Technically I was still a US employee assisting the other group. But that only works if the company already has offices in both countries. .. sometimes more locally than that ... and as I say that doesn't appear to be what they're looking for. Mine was a special case.)